# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo... NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, nullpointerexception

so I am getting this error, and i really don't know why, I already checked the manifest

```
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examaar/com.example.examaar.Final}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.example.examaar.DBHelper.selectAllBooks(DBHelper.java:85)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.example.examaar.Final.onCreate(Final.java:17)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-17 11:17:30.190: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 11 more
```

and here it is the code of the last activity (the one that triggers this Exception)

```
package com.example.examaar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
    public class Final extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.final1);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            final DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
            ArrayList<Libro> libros = db.selectAllBooks();
            String[] res= new String[libros.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<libros.size();i++){
                res[i]=libros.get(i).getusuario()+"-"+libros.get(i).getdestino()+"-"+libros.get(i).getfecha()+"-"+libros.get(i).gettransporte();
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, res);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
}
```

Comment: Looking further down in the stack trace, it shows that your `NullPointerException` is at line 85 in `DBHelper.selectAllBooks`. I suggest looking there for your issue, and posting your DBHelper code here if you are still stuck.

Comment: @Yjay yeah I tried but still no luck, in the second activity I implemented a log with the same value as res[i] in the last activity, and It gave me a result.

Comment: ok I found what triggered the exception, it is the selectAllBooks but it is not wrong, I just realized that in my last activity a connection wasn't created with my database. wow, rockie mistake!

Comment: so @Yjay if you could answer the question so I can accept your answer as a solution, because it helped me.

Comment: DBHelper.java:85 null pointer error at this line check what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `lol[i]`. But you are not creating any array with `lol` name. This is the reason of error. So create array with `lol[]` name and then run your code.

Comment: yeah it was a mistake I forgot to change, I realised that after I posted the code here I already editted, but still, it gives me the same Exception, it tries to load the last activity, the screen goes black and then returns to the second activity.

Comment: means now its running?

Comment: the last acivity is the only one that doesn't work, it is the one thtat triggers this exception